# Python3 open buffering argument looks strange

Tags: python-3.x, io, python-3.7

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
>   Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to
>   select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1
>   to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no
>   buffering argument is given, the default buffering policy works as
>   follows:
>
> Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying
>   device’s “block size” and falling back on io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On
>   many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.
>       “Interactive” text files (files for which isatty() returns True) use line buffering. Other text files use the policy described above
>   for binary files.

I open a file named `test.log` with text mode, and set the buffering to 16. So I think the chunk size is 16, and when I write 32 bytes string to the file. It will call `write`(syscall) twice. But acutally, it only call once.(test in Python 3.7.2 GCC 8.2.1 20181127 on Linux)

```
import os


try:
    os.unlink('test.log')
except Exception:
    pass


with open('test.log', 'a', buffering=16) as f:
    for _ in range(10):
        f.write('a' * 32)
```

Using `strace -e write python3 test.py` to trace syscall, and get following

```
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 320) = 320
```

What does the `buffering` means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is valid for CPython 3.7 other implementations of Python can differ.

The `open()` function in text mode returns [`_io.TextIOWrapper()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1022). The `_io.TextIOWrapper()` has internal 'buffer' called [`pending_bytes`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_io/textio.c#L676) with size of 8192 bytes (it is [hard coded](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1156)) and it also have handle on `_io.BufferedWriter()` for text mode `w` or `_io.BufferedRandom()` for text mode `a`. The size of `_io.BufferedWriter()`/`_io.BufferedRandom()` is specified by the argument `buffering` in the `open()` function.

When you call into `_io.TextIOWrapper().write("some text")` it will add the text into internal `pending_bytes` buffer. After some writes you will fill the `pending_bytes` buffer and then it will be written into buffer inside `_io.BufferedWriter()`. When you fill up also the buffer inside `_io.BufferedWriter()` then it will be written into target file.

When you open file in binary mode you will get directly the `_io.BufferedWriter()`/`_io.BufferedRandom()` object initialized with buffer size from `buffering` parametr.

Let's look at some examples. I will start with simpler one using binary mode.

```
# Case 1
with open('test.log', 'wb', buffering=16) as f:
    for _ in range(5):
        f.write(b'a'*15)
```

strace output:

```
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 15)         = 15
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 15)         = 15
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 15)         = 15
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 15)         = 15
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 15)         = 15
```

In the first iteration it fill buffer with 15 bytes. In the second iteration it discovers that adding another 15 bytes would overflow the buffer so it first flush it (calls system `write`) and then save those new 15 bytes. In next iteration the same happens again. After last iteration in the buffer is 15 B which are written on close of the file (leaving the `with` context).

The second case, I will try write into buffer more data than the buffer's size:

```
# Case 2
with open('test.log', 'wb', buffering=16) as f:
    for _ in range(5):
        f.write(b'a'*17)
```

strace output:

```
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 17)       = 17
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 17)       = 17
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 17)       = 17
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 17)       = 17
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 17)       = 17
```

What happens here is that in the first iteration it will try write into buffer 17 B but it cannot fit there so it is directly written into the file and buffer stays empty. This applies for every iteration.

Now let's look at the text mode.

```
# Case 3
with open('test.log', 'w', buffering=16) as f:
    for _ in range(5):
        f.write('a'*8192)
```

strace output:

```
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 16384) = 16384
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 16384) = 16384
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 8192) = 8192
```

First recall that `pending_bytes` has size 8192 B. In the first iteration it writes 8192 bytes (from code: `'a'*8192`) into `pending_bytes` buffer. In the second iteration it adds to the `pending_buffer` another 8192 bytes and discovers it is more than 8192 (size of `pending_bytes` buffer) and writes it into underlying `_io.BufferedWriter()`. The buffer in  `_io.BufferedWriter()` has size 16 B (`buffering` parameter) so it will immediately writes into file (same as case 2). Now the `pending_buffer` is empty and in the third iteration it's again filled with 8192 B. In the fourth iteration it adds another 8192 B `pending_bytes` buffer overflows and it again written directly into file as in the second iteration. In the last iteration it adds 8192 B into `pending_bytes` buffer which is flushed when the files is closed.

Last example contains buffering bigger than 8192 B. Also for better explanation I added 2 more iterations.

```
# Case 4
with open('test.log', 'w', buffering=30000) as f:
    for _ in range(7):
        f.write('a'*8192)
```

strace output:

```
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 16384) = 16384
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 16384) = 16384
write(3, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., 24576) = 24576
```

Iterations:

1. Add 8192 B into `pending_bytes`.
2. Add 8192 B into `pending_bytes` but it is more than maximal size so it is written into underlying `_io.BufferedWritter()` and it stays there (`pending_bytes` is empty now).
3. Add 8192 B into `pending_bytes`.
4. Add 8192 B into `pending_bytes` but it is more than maximal size so it tries to write into into underlying `_io.BufferedWritter()`. But it would exceed maximal capacity of the underlying buffer cause `16384 + 16384 > 30000` (first 16384 B are still there from iteration 2) so it first writes the old 16384 B into file and then puts those new 16384 B (from `pending_bytes`) into buffer. (Now again the `pending_bytes` buffer is empty)
5. Same as 3
6. Same as 4
7. Currently `pending_buffer` is empty and `_io.BufferedWritter()` contains 16384 B. In this iteration it fills `pending_buffer` with 8192 B. And that's it.

When the program leave `with` section it close the file. The process of closing follows:

1. Writes 8192 B from `pending_buffer` into `_io.BufferedWriter()` (it is possible cause `8192 + 16384 < 30000`)
2. Writes (`8192 + 16384`=) 24576 B into file.
3. Close the file descriptor.

Btw currently I have no idea why is there that `pending_buffer` when it can use for buffering the underlying buffer from `_io.BufferedWritter()`. My best guess is it's there because it improve performance with files working in text mode.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It's very useful answer. I check the CPython source code. And I find that as you say. In TextIOWrapper, it has 8192 bytes buffer, and when call write, it will add string to pending_bytes, finally check the current size. if current size > chunk_size, it will write all to BufferedWritter. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34ef64fe5947bd7e1b075c785fc1125c4e600cd4/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1600. Actually the argument buffering is the size of BufferedWritter.It will write all when size > buffering https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1600